# Restore R Blogdown Site

Tags: r, blogdown

I updated my studious of R and RStudio, and had to reinstall some packages, including `blogdown`. I also had to reinstall the theme that I was using. When I did, I neglected to realize that it would replace all of my existing files and work... I'm wondering if anyone has tips on restoring, specifically on a mac! Time Machine is not being helpful, unfortunately

Comment: I don't think the process of downloading/updating themes stores backups of things that were over-written (sounds like a feature-request, tbh). When files are over-written, the general answer is "check your backup". If Time Machine is your method of backup and it is not a help here, I don't think there's anything that can be done. (I really hope somebody with more knowledge of `blogdown` internals can correct me, for your sake.) Perhaps https://www.macgasm.net/data-recovery/recover-replaced-files-mac/ gives you a glimmer of hope ...